# flatten a list of variable length arrays

Tags: python

how to convert this:

```
[2, 4, array([ 3.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 5.,  4.])]
```

to

```
[2,4,3,4,5,4]
```

I've tried searching but the solutions work for

```
[array([ 2.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 3.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 5.,  4.])]
```

and

```
[[2],[4],[3],[4],[5,4]]
```

Comment: What have you tried?  >>> [2,4,array([3.])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'array' is not defined

Comment: @JohnMee Maybe `numpy.array`.

Comment: @iMom0 hmm, given [the duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745090/python-list-to-array) you might be right. Still banging his drum but... you want to help him?

Comment: With variable lengths and nesting of numbers and lists I would try to make a recursive approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

a = [2, 4, array([ 3.]), array([ 4.]), array([ 5.,  4.])]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(np.asarray(b).ravel() for b in a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use sum for flattening things. In your case, you want to convert the arrays to lists and the numbers to lists of numbers, first. Thus if the array is in a:

```
sum((list(x) if hasattr(x, '__iter__') else [x] for x in a), [])
```

Comment: This will be very slow if you have many elements to deal with. With each step in the summation, a new list is allocated containing all elements seen so far. End result is worst-case O(n**2) time in the number of elements.

Comment: Premature optimization. If performance on long lists were a requirement, he would have said so. My solution is both more general and easier to read, and thus maintain, than your solution. Though yours certainly is better if there is a chance that there are many elements.